# Init static variable with static variable in C99

Tags: c, c99

Is it allowed to initialize static array with static array in C99?
Example:

```
static const char * const PATH1 = "/home/usr";
static const char * const PATH2 = "/usr/";
static const char * const PATH3 = ".";

static const char *path_list[] = {
    PATH1,
    PATH2,
    PATH3,
    0
};  

int main()
{
    char **path = (char **)path_list;

    while(*path)
    {
        printf("path[%s]\n", *path);
        path++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As I understood from C standard §6.7.8.:

> 1644 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has
>   static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

Is const char * const constant enough?
If not, is static variable initialization order defined somewhere?

Comment: [*"address constant expression, which is ... lvalue designating an object of static storage duration or a function designator, converted to a pointer"*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression)

Comment: The question is "is it officially allowed?". It does compile and does work. The problem is, that I'm not sure, that it is a valid code.

Comment: @incogn1to Which compiler? Which options? With gcc I get `error: initializer element is not constant`

Comment: When compiled with `g++` it is an endless loop

Comment: @4386427 That's because the condition doesn't change inside the loop.

Comment: @tuple_cat - I know but it wrote it because OP told that it did work :-)

Comment: Stupid of me not to try it on GCC. ARMCC does compile this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the static zone all the variables, if initialized, must be initialized with `Integer constants` and other `constant expressions`.

The values of other static variables are not considered constants.

The constants are enumerators, raw numbers (1, 3.1, 1e10...), 'c' characters, string literals "constant", initializer-list such as {1,2,3}.

Statement from `6.7.8 Initialization`:

4. **`All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.`**

Answer (score 1):

The value of a variable will always be considered "run time" whereas initializers for static or global variables must be "compile time". So what you wrote won't work. What you can do of course is use the pre-processor:

```
#define C_PATH1 "/home/usr"
#define C_PATH2 "/usr/"
#define C_PATH3 "."

static const char * const PATH1 = C_PATH1;
static const char * const PATH2 = C_PATH2;
static const char * const PATH3 = C_PATH3;

static const char *path_list[] = {
    C_PATH1,
    C_PATH2,
    C_PATH3,
    0
};
```